# How can I fetch the nested relation through a single statement into an array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have four models each having hasMany relations to each other.

A hasMany B
B hasMany C
C hasMany D

My main model is A and I want to fetch D through A. I am querying like this to get D.

```
A::with('B.C.D')->get();
```

I am fetching D like this:

```
$answer = [];
foreach(A as a) {
    foreach(a->B as b){
        foreach(b->C as c) {
            foreach(c->D as d) {
                $answer[] = d;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

But I want to reduce these arrays into a single statement, is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pluck()` and `collapse()`.

```
A::with('B.C.D')->get()->pluck('B.*.C.*.D.*')->collapse();
```

It directly gives you D's model data.

Let me know its solve your issue or not.

Comment: The pleasure is all mine. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel [Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers)  [`data_get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-data-get) to get nested data easily.
Laravel has a lots of helper functions . Going through these function helps a lot.

In your case:

```
data_get($variable, 'a.b.c')
```